# Numbers mod 11 Order

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can you show that for all positive integers that are 10 mod 11, none of them have digits that increase at any point? I ran a Python program for numbers up to the millions checking, and I couldn't find any numbers that are 10 mod 11 that also have digits that increase at any point, so I'm inclined to believe it's true.

Comment: Less confusing is to say "Can you show that all positive integers that are 10 (mod 11) have non-increasing digits".

Comment: @croraf `have non-increasing digits` is not equivalent to (and stronger than) "*do not have non-decreasing digits*" which is what the question asks. Consider for example that $\,9 \cdot 11 + 10 = 109\,$, and $\,109\,$ has neither non-increasing nor non-decreasing digits.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, why should the 2nd rightmost digit be $0$? Another idea: if $n$ has non-decreasing digits and at least 2 digits, let $d$ be the leftmost digit. Subtract from $n$ the number whose digits are $dd00\ldots$, with enough $0$s to make it the same length as $n$. The result is congruent to $n$ modulo $11$, still has non-decreasing digits, and has fewer digits than $n$. Keep doing this and we get down to a single digit or $0$, which is obviously not congruent to $10$ modulo $11$.

Comment: `why should the 2nd rightmost digit be 0` If that's about my now-deleted answer, then that was wrong and I removed it.